# Task alerts ala Outlook with Google Calendar/Chrome?

Tags: notifications, google-chrome, tasks

The only feature I miss from Outlook after we made the switch to Google Apps at work is the alarm popup that arose when you programmed it. Outlook had lots of options when programming the alarm or interval. I've been looking for something similar from a Chrome app but I was not successful.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

In chrome got to:

`Tools –> Options –> Under the Hood –> Content settings.`

**Notifications** check:

`Ask me when a site wants to show desktop notifications`

Then go to your calender and open the settings and click on the `labs` tab

and enable the `Gentle Reminders` lab hit save and your done

**REF:** [Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28573/how-to-enable-desktop-notifications-for-google-calendar-in-chrome/)

Comment: I used that right now, but it's not as flexible as Outlook. For example, the popup does not have an option to change the next reminder to some day and hour, or a week, or a month, etc. as Outlook.

Comment: @Gabriel that's not really possible with Google Calendar.. unless they will implement it and right now it's not! It would require to popup another window and usually they are blocked so I don't think that it will be implemented at all.. notifications it's a new thing and it's the closes that you can get

Comment: @Gabriel you could use it along side [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eaipgbekceebhbboemgghnjhnamflgmp?hl=en) as this would allow you to edit the event without having to leave your current browser page